# ASP.NET MVC Session is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been assigned to customize this MVC application. It has Forms Authentication, and I was instructed to customize it so that the "Login" Process is eliminated and all users can access the app. The application was built so that all operations are done around the logged in User.

Since I needed an authenticated user, I took the code which was responsible to log in and authenticate the user and put it in Application_AcquireRequestState

This is my Login Code:

```
public Action Login(string username, string password)
{
 bool loginResult = false;
 try
 {
     // If validated, it sets the LoginStatus to true and populates the Variables for security
     bool validate = this.memberShip.ValidateUser(username,password);

     if (validate)
     {
         // CxIdentity extends and implements IIdentity
         var identity = new CxIdentity(memberShip.LoginStatus.SecurityUser.Name,
                            memberShip.LoginStatus.SecurityUser.Id,
                            "",
                            true);

         this.Session[this.memberShip.PrincipalSessionKey] = new CxPrincipal(identity, memberShip.LoginStatus.SecurityUser.RoleId);
         this.Session[SessionName.CurrentUser] = memberShip.LoginStatus.SecurityUser.UserNm;
         FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false, "MyApp/Cookies");

         loginResult = true;
     }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     Logger.Error("Login failed: ", ex);
  }
  if(loginResult)
      return Redirect("~/Home");
  else
      return Redirect("~/Login");
}
```

And the following is the code of Application_AcquireRequestState, prior to when I tried to merge it

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Handler is IRequiresSessionState)
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session[this.MemberShipProvider.PrincipalSessionKey] != null)
            {
                CxPrincipal principal;

                try
                {
                    principal = (CxPrincipal)HttpContext.Current.Session[this.MemberShipProvider.PrincipalSessionKey];
                }
                catch
                {
                    principal = null;
                }

                HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
             }
             else
             {
                 if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && User.Identity is FormsIdentity)
                 {
                     FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                     Response.Redirect("~/Login");
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

The application was written is such a way that if the User isn't Authenticated the applciation will go drectly to Login page. So I changed the Application_AcquireRequestState as follows:

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     if (HttpContext.Current.Handler is IRequiresSessionState)
     {

          var sessioncheck = this.Session[SessionName.CurrentUser];
          var obj = this.Session[this.MemberShipProvider.PrincipalSessionKey];
          if (obj != null)
          {
              HttpContext.Current.User = (CxPrincipal)obj;
              Thread.CurrentPrincipal = (CxPrincipal)obj;
           } 
           else
           {
               this.MemberShipProvider.ValidateUser("appadmin", "@dmin#@!8854");
               var identity = new CxIdentity("appadmin", 1, "", true);
               CxPrincipal principalLogin = new CxPrincipal(identity, 1);
               this.Session[this.MemberShipProvider.PrincipalSessionKey] = principalLogin;
               this.Session[SessionName.CurrentUser] = "appadmin";                       

               FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("appadmin", false, "MyApp/Cookies");
            }
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
               if (this.Session[this.MemberShipProvider.PrincipalSessionKey] != null)
               {
                    CxPrincipal principal;
                    try
                    {
                        principal = (CxPrincipal)this.Session[this.MemberShipProvider.PrincipalSessionKey];
                     }
                     catch
                     {
                          principal = null;
                     }
                     HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
                     Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
                }

           }
      }                

 }
```

The problem is that everytime I check obj, it is always null.  The Request.IsAuthenticated also gets true and while the application is within the acquire state the session does get set (that is why I get values in HttpContext.Current.User and Thread.CurrentPrincipal.

But when I redirect to another page, the session is gone.

Can anyone guide me through this.

Comment: What is timeout of session ?

Comment: It is the default. Can you tell me why I am losing my sessions?

Comment: set a timeout for session and than check

Comment: <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30" /> This is what I have

Comment: did you solve??